# Can Hyperledger Fabric Assets/Data be decimal values or only integers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm working with an HL consultant on a project who is telling me that we can only store integer numbers in the HL database/assets. Somehow this seems strange to me and an odd limitation in HL. I'm having difficulty finding the answer in the manuals.

Is he correct? We need to be able to store a decimal value, i.e. 2.70

Thanks (apologies for this basic question, I've never worked with HL before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not correct. Fabric [stores](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/blob/master/shim/interfaces.go#L91) key-value pairs in which the key is a string, and the value is a byte array.

```
PutState(key string, value []byte) error
```

Answer (score 0):

Yacov is correct, especially given that he is one of the authors of Hyperledger Fabric.

However, there might be the case that the chaincode that has been written and is instantiated, only accepts integer numbers. Meaning there is some business logic added which parses the received arguments and only accepts parsing to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger fabric  don't care about value, it could be anything.
Infact we could restrict to add specific value by defining struct as below

```
type Contract struct {
    ID             int  `json:"id"`
    TypeOfContract string  `json:"typeOfContract"`
    Title          string  `json:"title"`
    Owner          string  `json:"owner"`
    Contract       string  `json:"contract"`
    Price          float32  `json:"contract"`
    Status         string  `json:"status"`
    Steps          []Steps `json:"steps"`
}
```

Without struct as well we can add data.

Comment: how to achieve that in javascript without using typescript?